# AWS Rekognition not recognizing image as bytes

Tags: amazon-web-services

Getting error in AWS

```
InvalidParameterException: Requested image should either contain bytes or s3 object.
```

console.log(imageBuffer) shows
[image]

Code that passes the image to AWS function

```
  const moderateEachPic = async (image) => {
    let imageBuffer;
    imageBuffer = new Uint8Array(await image.arrayBuffer())
    // moderate image using AWS Rekognition
    console.log(imageBuffer)
    await verifyImage (imageBuffer).then((res) => {
     ....
    })
  }
```

This is the function to call AWS Rekognition

```
var rekognition = new RekognitionClient({
  credentials: creds,
  region: region,
})

export async function verifyImage (image ) {
  console.log(image)
  const params = {
    Image:{
      image
   },
   Attributes: ['ALL']
  };

  const command = new DetectFacesCommand(params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-rekognition/interfaces/image.html#bytes) per the AWS SDK has two properties, `Bytes` and `S3Object`. You have to set those appropriately in order to have your example work.

I can't get your sample to run locally, but, try this:

```
var rekognition = new RekognitionClient({
  credentials: creds,
  region: region,
})

export async function verifyImage (image ) {
  console.log(image)
  const params = {
    Image: {
        Bytes: image,
    },
   },
   Attributes: ['ALL']
  };

  const command = new DetectFacesCommand(params);
```